# Throughput and latency

Tags: system-design

Each machine has 5 cores each with 2 threads for concurrent requests; how many machines would we require for 1K RPS throughput and 1sec latency.

I am not sure if there is any way to calculate the no of machines with the data that is given.

Answer (score 0):

Each machine has 5 cores with 2 threads for concurrent requests, hence
The total number of concurrent requests handled by a machine: 5*2=10
The number of requests the system will receive from clients: 1K
So, the number of machines required to handle 1K RPS = 1000/10 = 100 machines.